# How to pass a variable from html to a document ready function

Tags: python, html, document-ready

I need to pass a variable from my html code to the document ready function.

my HTML code has 
`<p>Welcome {{ajax_data}}</p>`: ajax_data is being passed from my python code

Now what I need in my document ready function is the value of the ajax_data. For now I have hardcoded it

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{
    //ajax row data
    
    var data =
    [
        {"fname":"Code", "lname":"With Mark", "email":"mark@codewithmark.com"},
        {"fname":"Mary", "lname":"Moe", "email":"mary@gmail.com"},
        {"fname":"John", "lname":"Doe", "email":"john@yahoo.com"},
        {"fname":"Julie", "lname":"Dooley", "email":"julie@gmail.com"},
    ]
```

what i need is to pass the value of {{ajax_data}} inside the function to the variable data. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks
jaideep

Comment: Make an ajax call to server endpoint and make it return json array? Is it to hacky?

Comment: am kind of newbie, sorry about that. will be great if you can share the code that i need to put on my html file or any references to similar query..i can read and try to understand more